# In Visual Studio 2022, can you autohide the references window when clicking a reference in it?

Tags: reference, visual-studio-2022

I am used to working with Jetbrains IDEs where you bring up references, click one and then the references window closes right away.

Visual Studio does not close the references window (brought up via shift-f12) when you click a reference or the editor and it is quite annoying because it adds a small delay in my workflow now and I use reference quite frequently. I have to move the mouse to the editor and wait an ungodly amount of time before it will close. Even worse, the references window covers the code it jumps too! It does not even scroll it to the visible portion of the editor.

Please tell me there is a way to speed up this workflow.

Comment: It may depend on how the window is docked. Try docking it on the lowest part of the screen? And then make sure it's not pinned